# Change property using URL rewrite - IIS8 - Windows Server 2012

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012, rewrite, url

I have a webserver with two domains and both with ssl, I saw a video about how to configure this (SSL) and everything worked well but now my problem is that there is a part about URL rewrite WHERE if I write something like `example.com` it redirects to `https://example.com` and its ok but now if I want to write `www.example.com` it changes to `https://www.example.com` but it says that cannot access to the site but before SSL it was working, I need to access to this site with both ways

This is my URL rewrite configuration

[First capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j29Oy.png)

[Second capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSDzF.png)

What I need to change to make `https://www.example.com` available again?